# Using cookies for notifications to disappear

Tags: html, css, cookies

I'm new to this.. cookie thing, but a friend of mine told me to check it out if I wanted my notification to disappear.

this is what I have

```
<font style="float:right">
          <nav class="dropdownContainer">
             <span class="lightpill-n dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bell dropdown-toggle"></i> 1</span>
               <ul class="dropdown">
                 <span class="text1">
                 Hello!
                 <p>We updated a few changes to the website. Keep yourself updated by reading more.
                   <p>
                     <span class="btn-read" style="text-align:right;">Read more</span>
               </span>
               </ul>
             </nav>
            </font>
```

When it's checked, I want this div to change.

```
<span class="lightpill-warn dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bell dropdown-toggle"></i> 1</span>
```

To this:

```
<span class="lightpill-n dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bell dropdown-toggle"></i> </span>
```

I don't know if it's possible? But I hope it is, so I don't need to change the code all the time to take it away.

Comment: CSS and HTML are markup languages. If you want to use cookies you'll have to use JavaScript, PHP or some other actual programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a server or a client side langauge like PHP or Javascript to do that. HTML is only a markup language (no logic).

Hope I helped you.